# uploadify: Firefox browser does not display upload file button

Tags: uploadify

Folks,

I am using uploadify component (http://www.uploadify.com) in ASP.NET MVC 3. uploadify works fine with all browser (IE 8, Google Chrome). However, Mozilla Firefox does not display upload file button.
I have spent almost one day to troubleshoot and I still have not solution. Could you give some idea?

Comment: Does it work for you in their demo?

Comment: i tried to open http://www.uploadify.com/demos/ from Mozilla and the upload button is not displayed. do you have  work around?

Comment: It works fine for me.  You probably have a local problem with Flash Player.

Comment: really? could you tell me your flash player edition ?

Answer (score 4):

I just got a new computer and installed firefox (V8.0.1) yesterday.  I've just experienced a similar issue (i.e. not seeing the uploadify button in firefox, though I do in chrome - both in the site I'm developing and http://www.uploadify.com/demos/).  Using firefox I've browsed to http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/plugincheck/. There I'm told "For your safety, Firefox has disabled your outdated version of Flash. Please upgrade to the latest version.". I've upgraded the version of Flash and now when I visit the uploadify demo page I can see the "Select Files" button, as expected.

Comment: Yes. I managed to solve the issue by updating with the latest flash player.

Answer (score 0):

Install adobe flash player...it will work properly....